# How to make browser window to run in background when running JUnit with Selenium WebDriver from IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, junit, linux-mint

I am running automation tests on Selenium WebDriver as JUnit tests from IntellijIdea.
When a browser opens and some actions are being done in it then it always brings itself to the front, even if I have tab-ed to other window. This is not very convenient. Some tests run for few minutes and I would like to be able to work on some other tasks while they are running. Or in case if I want to run the whole suite I can't just sit and watch for 30 minutes.

I started to have this problem after I switched from Windows OS to Linux Mint. On Windows browser remained in the background and did not bother me.
Is there any way to configure such behavior on Linux Mint OS?

I have already tried to run the browser/IntelliJ Idea in a separate LinuxMint's workspace, doesn't help. The browser window pops up in the other workspace as soon as some activity is being done there.
Also I've set this config in LinuxMint's windows behavior settings:
[image]

Comment: This may be operating system specific (but i have a similar issue, but on OSX rather than linux). 

Perhaps try to work around the issue by using phamtomjs (https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver), if that still works with the newer webdriver protocol. Unfortunately, that's not a good solution if you actually need the actual browser (say, for browser specific conditions/tests).

Comment: Chii, phantomjs is not an option for me. I really need browser and doing a lot of stuff in it.

Answer (score 4):

As of this week (chrome 57 or higher) it is possible to run [chrome in headless mode](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md). To do this you simply pass the --headless flag.

To pass this flag to chrome via Selenium webdriver you can use the following code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");

ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I'm not sure if this solves the focus issue completely though.. In my case there is still a chrome window stealing focus, but I think it is a big improvement as the window doesn't pop up in front of what I'm doing.

I think it's definitely worth a shot. I will continue to look at the focus issue and update if I find something.

Comment: I've tried and got this exception:
`An exception or error caused a run to abort: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html`

Comment: What are your chromedriver and Selenium versions? I found the following : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3508
Seems like there are still some compatibility issues regarding Selenium, chromedriver and chrome 57

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you upgraded your chrome version and enabled the headless mode 'at the same time' is that true? Does it behave the same way when you don't add the headless flag?

Comment: I already had Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) of the Chrome. 
My selenium version is 3.1.0.
My ChromeDriver version is 2.28.455506.
And of course it does not behave the same when I add the headless flag, because I tried to add it in my working project which has tons of working tests. So only if I add the flag then I am getting the exception. Also I am on Linux. So probably I need to wait some more time to be able to test this, till the guys in the ChromeDriver team polish this feature. Anyway, thank you for pointing out this potentially useful feature.

Comment: @in016hoe exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium doesn't have a built in method for minimizing the browser, however you can take out of sight by using:

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-2000, 0));
```

While this 'hack' will move the browser window out of sight, when the driver is initialized the browser will be visible for a short moment.

Comment: Possible minor inconvenient: this may be a nice workaround if the browser window does not get focused as well, case in which you'd also have to click back to your previously active window.

Comment: I've just tried it and it is not helping. It still steals the focus to the browser window but now some elements of the page are not visible for the driver and tests are failing with exceptions then. Thanks for the idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try using RemoteDriver and it will execute code with minimized browser. Give your localhost ip as a host address. Code would look like this.

```
  try {


    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList(
                "--start-maximized", "--disable-popup-blocking"));
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/BrowserDrivers/chromedriver.exe");
        // Code to faster execution on Chrome 
        ChromeOptions chromOpt = new ChromeOptions();
        chromOpt.addArguments("Proxy","null");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,chromOpt );
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub"), capabilities);*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: QA Square, I have not worked with a RemoteWebriver before but what I see from docs is that it is needed in case I want to work with Selenium Grid, i.e. when I want to run tests on different machines.
In my case I run tests on one machine and use FirefoxDriver. As I see from your example when instantiating a RemoreWebDriver I can set it to work with Chrome browser, and I assume I will be able to also use Firefox. But also you pass some URL to the driver constructor. What is this URL? I would not like to use Selenium Grid.

Comment: You dont require selenium Grid to run remoteDriver if you want to run on a single machine or your own machine.  Try the code I have pasted, it will work.

Comment: Will I be able to see what's going on in the browser if I need to view?

Comment: The code is not working straight away. I researched a bit and I see now that in order to use this RemoteWebDriver I need to run the standalone selenium jar with `hub` parameter. This is not what I really need. RemoreWebDriver is for scenarios when you have server and client, even if you want to have it locally it looks like server should be started locally anyway on the particular port, as `5555` in your example.
I don't want to go for that, tests already working fine, I just need a way to make focus not moving to the active background bowser window.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that solutions you're looking for is called *virtual display*, you need to create virtual display and execute your tests in there. Look for **xvfb**. However, I'm not 100% it will work with Chrome.
Another option that you have is to create virtual machine(using virtualbox, for example) under linux and use **Selenium Grid** to connect to it.

Comment: Mikhail, I used xvbf when I needed to run tests on a headless Linux machine. Now I am just looking for solution which will not move focus on the browser window when tests are running there.